# Event is not fired (WPF control and MVVMLight)

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, routed-events

I have a slider with a LowerValueChangedEvent event:

```
    public static readonly RoutedEvent LowerValueChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("LowerValueChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<DateTime>), typeof(DateRangeSlider));
    public event RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<DateTime> LowerValueChanged
    {
        add { AddHandler(LowerValueChangedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(LowerValueChangedEvent, value); }
    }
```

The event is never triggered.

Is it a registration error? I set a breakpoint into the AddHandler line, but it never gets hit.

I'm using MVVMLight.

I don't understand where the error is.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should add a bit more code in your answer: where you register to that event and where the event is raised. It is a class that inhered from a slider?